# `DatePickerInput` "className" property for `<input />`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using the [`DatePickerInput`](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/) react component and want to style the `<input />` element inside. With the component's `className` property I can only style the `<div />` container around. Using `classNames` object property also styles other containers.

So is it possible and if it is, how, to apply a CSS class *directly* to the `<input />` element (I'm using Bootstrap so I want to add the class "form-control" for consistency)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`inputProps`](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput) prop to pass a `className` prop explicitly to the input. This prop should be an object with key/value pairs corresponding to the props for the input:

```
<DayPickerInput inputProps={{ className: 'form-control' }} … />
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I should have seen that it is that easy (Y)